Performance of using map once vs. multiple times
For most of my development career, I was convinced that iterating over an array multiple times should be avoided.
After a lot of back and forth, I'm not so sure anymore, so I'd like to ask for your opinion.
Which of the following two examples is more performant? Both seem to me to use the same amount of CPU cycles.
arrayOfAThousandElements.map(x => {doSmth(x); doSmthElse(x)})
This uses 1000*2 cpu cycles, given that doSmth and doSmthElse use only one cycle.
arrayOfAThousandElements.map(x => doSmth(x)).map(x => doSmthElse(x))
This uses 1000 + 1000 CPU-Cycles.
The second solution "feels" slower to me. But i cant argue about it. Am i missing something?

You should write a test for this and run it to see what result you get.

The second creates 2 arrays, while the first only creates one. This at least involves extra work for memory allocation.

Why not just benchmark it and get an objective measurement as opposed to asking for “[our] opinion”?

why use map at all? you don't appear to be using the resulting arrays...

The overhead of the looping is usually negligible compared to what you're doing inside the loops. So unless the function bodies are really trivial, it won't make a huge difference.

@HereticMonkey The same question arises with forEach(). Although in that case, you have to use map() for the first loop so have an array to pass to forEach().

@Barmar Unless doSmth does nothing to x, in which case running another forEach on arrayOfAThousandElements is the same. Looks like someone using map for looping to me.

The second solution will be a little slower. Your comparison of "CPU cycles" is ignoring the overhead of the iteration itself (which is doubled), as well as the overhead of creating the intermediate array. But unless the functions are very simple, this overhead will usually be negligible.
Note also that the two codes aren't actually equivalent. Your second version is actually equivalent to
arrayOfAThousandElements.map(x => doSmthElse(doSmth(x)))

because the first map() returns an array of the results of doSmth(x), and that's what gets mapped by the second map(). They would only be equivalent if doSmth() returns its argument.
To make them really equivalent, you should not chain the calls:
arrayOfAThousandElements.map(x => doSmth(x));
arrayOfAThousandElements.map(x => doSmthElse(x));

Note also that if you're not using the result of .map() you should use .forEach() instead. This avoids the unnecessary overhead of creating an array of results.
